# Performance Tuning Base64 encoding

Tags: delphi, base64

I've been trying to get a relatively optimized version of base64 encoding that works against files.  However, I've made several attempts and haven't gotten anything much faster than what I have here.  On the posted implementation, I started from what was posted on http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1524 .  I have to think there's a way to do it without tossing values around in a, so I tried that by processing three bytes at a time and then processing the rest, but I didn't end up with anything faster.  So, does anyone have any ideas on how to improve it any more from a speed perspective?

(Relevant code below, I slid some global definitions into the first procedure so people could see those.  Codes64 is the string I'm using to encode the data
with, not reproduced here for brevity)

```
procedure TMyMimeEncoder.Enc64Buffer(inbuf, outbuf: pointer; inbufsize:  longint;
        var outbufsize: longint);
 // run on the buffer read in by the file (inbuf).  Outbuf is the output.
  type
    PByteArray1 = ^TByteArray1;
    TByteArray1 = array[1..buffersize] of Byte;
  var
    a, b: longint;
    inproc: PByteArray1 absolute inbuf;
    outproc: PChar;
    i: longint;
  begin
    outproc := outbuf;
    outbufsize := 0;
    for i := 1 to inbufsize do
      begin
        b := (b shl 8) + inproc^[i];
        a := a + 8;
        if a = 12 then
          begin
            a := a - 6;
            outproc^ := Codes64[(b shr a)];
            b := b and ((1 shl a) - 1);
            inc(outproc, 1);
            inc(outbufsize, 1);
          end;
        a := a - 6;
        outproc^ := Codes64[(b shr a)];
        b := b and ((1 shl a) - 1);
        inc(outproc, 1);
        inc(outbufsize, 1);
      end;
  end;

function TMyMimeEncoder.Enc64Final: String;
  // run at the end of file to finish the encoding.
  begin
    Result := '';
    if a = 4 then
      Result := Codes64[(b shl 2) + 1] + '='
    else
    if a = 2 then
      Result := Codes64[(b shl 4) + 1] + '==';
  end;
```

Comment: I have a different version of this now with much smaller numbers of instructions.  I figured out the main issue is with the output buffer assigns (my guess about 20% of the total run when I comment those lines out).  If anyone has any ideas in that realm, I'd appreciate them.